# R - Different length in variable and residuals from the model

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, cox-regression, cox

I'm trying to find the the best variable transformation that yields linearity in log hazard or log cumulative hazard of a Cox proportional Hazard model. As those ar research data, I cannot publish them here. For this I'm trying to plot the variable against the residuals by using this code.

```
cox_mod_spline = coxph(Surv(timespan_censored,status)~ risk_factor, data = df)
res = residuals(cox_mod_spline, type = "martingale")
df$risk_factor
plot(na.omit(df$risk_factor), res)
```

However I get this error message : `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Indeed when I enter this code:

```
length(df$risk_factor)
length(res)
```

I get

```
[1] 587
[1] 577
```

respectively

I also checked that there are no `NA` in `df$risk_factor`

why do the residuals and the variable differ in length given the fact that the residuals are created FROM the variable itself?

Comment: Probably observations with `NA`s that were dropped automatically by the model.

Comment: Thank you @alistaire. But it seems to me highly unlikely as rhere are NO ’NA’ in the variable risk factor and that res were created from this variable and hence should have the same length

Comment: @ecjb it can be because of dropping observations due to `NA` in one of the other variables considered in model. (not necessarily risk factor)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mankind_008. But that does does not convince me neither because as you can see it is an univariate (and not multiple) cox regression. Hence the NA in other variables should not be considered